# printing only specific lines with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, gnu

I have following File (*wishlist.txt*):

```
Alligatoah Musik_ist_keine_lösung;https:///uhfhf
Alligatoah STRW;https:///uhfhf?i
Amewu Entwicklungshilfe;https:///uhfhf?i
```

and want to have the first word of line *n*.
so for *n* = 1:

```
Alligatoah
```

What i have so far is:

```
sed -e 's/\s.*//g' wishlist.txt
```

is there a elegant way to get rid of all lines except *n*?

Edit:

How to pass a bash variable "*$i*" to sed since

```
sed -n '$is/ .*//p' $wishlist
```

and

```
sed -n "\`${i}\`s/ .*//p" $wishlist
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. For the 1st word of the 3rd line.

```sh
sed -n '3s/\s.*//p' wishlist.txt
```

To use a variable: Note: Double quotes.

```sh
line=3; sed -n "${line}s/\s.*//p" wishlist.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of other techniques to get the first word of the 3rd line:

```sh
awk -v line=3 'NR == line {print $1; exit}' file
```

or

```sh
head -n 3 file | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Comment: I like the `awk` one because it won't crash even when the input is not an integer

Comment: @Fravadona you should also like the awk one because it's clear, simple, robust, efficient, easily maintainable and extensible and will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box (unlike every sed answer posted so far which all require GNU sed).

Answer (score 0):

`sed` supports "addresses", so you can tell it what lines to operate on. To print only the first line, you can use

```
sed -e '1!d; s/\s.*//'
```

where `1!d` means: *on lines other then 1, delete the line*.

Comment: Thank you! Exacly what i was searching for.
I Knew about '1d' but didn't know it could be inverted.

I was about to do my creative solution:
``` grep -n '' wishlist.txt | grep ^1 | sed -e 's/\s.*//g' -e 's/^.://g'

Comment: @definitiv `\s` is non standard. You can also use `sed -n '1s/ .*//p'` as its probably more readable.

Comment: One more question: how can i use a variable? "sed -e '$i!d (...) doesn't work..

Comment: @definitiv `sed -n $i's/ .*//p'`

Comment: @definitiv: Single quotes don't expand variables. Double quotes do.